How to get historical calibration data for mthree (M3) from IBM Quantum devices?
I'm using mthree in Batch mode. A batch needs to be queued before it can be executed. The time when a batch was executed can be obtained from the IBM Quantum Platform site, so I would like to obtain calibration data by specifying that time later.
A similar question is discussed at How to download historical calibration data from IBM quantum devices?. However, it seems that this method cannot obtain calibration data for mthree.
If you have a better method, please let me know. Thanks.
